# How to do casting to string with numba?

Tags: python, numba

Maybe I missed something of the documentation, but I cannot see any workaround or way of handling `str` casting in `numba`.

So even taking `numba.types.string` fails (see code below).

How can I cast to string in a numba optimized function?

```
import numba as nb

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def foo(a, b):
    f = nb.types.string(a) + b
    # f = str(a) + b

    return f


foo(123, '456')
```

error:

```
numba.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Invalid use of typeref[unicode_type] with parameters (int64)
No type info available for typeref[unicode_type] as a callable.
[1] During: resolving callee type: typeref[unicode_type]
[2] During: typing of call at <input> (5)
```